# unable to get response from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, sockets, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to login to a site which requires authendication and try to download a file

my code:

```
 import requests
 site_url='https://www.example.com'
 userid='abc'
 password='abc123'
 resp = requests.get(site_url, auth=(userid, password))
```

but I am getting `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))` please help.

Comment: `site_url:'https://www.example.com'` → `site_url = 'https://www.example.com'`

Comment: Missing schema : `invalid URL`

Comment: It's probable that the remote site didn't accept your request. There might be various reasons why this happens. Are you sure the remote server actually accepts basic auth vs some other kind of authentication.

Comment: How to check that

Comment: You should get a http response with status `401 Unauthorized` if your http request was well formed, but the password was wrong. But there might be some sort of firewall or server config that blocks certain types of requests. For example they might not like bots to download files, so you could try to use a fake user agent header.

Comment: okay, is there any other way to login and download the file ?, thank you ill try with user-agent

Comment: Depends on the server in question. They might have some documentation about how you can do it on their web page.

Comment: I logged in with the `fake user agent` but when I am downloading the file `requests.get(file_url).content` I am getting `Attention: Cookies must be enabled to access` from site server

Comment: how to handle session in this case @HåkenLid

Comment: There are examples in the requests docs of how to use a session.
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: thank you , I used requests.Session() and able to get the cookies but when I try downloading the file i used `s.get(file_url,cookies=resp.cookies).content` still same response